# What Do You Call Objects Created To Be Returned From Mocks?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, tdd

Is there a term for objects that are created solely to be returned from mocked methods in a unit tests?

An object created to assert against is *expected*. 
What you actually got is *actual*. 
Stuff you put in is *input*.

What do you call objects that you're making only to then pass to `.andReturn(someObject)` calls in your mocking framework of choice? I find it makes data-intensive tests much harder to understand if there's no naming convention for such objects.

Comment: Mock objects may return other mocks or real objects, which in turn may return mocks etc. so I don't think they have a name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gerard Meszaros' book "xUnit Test Patterns : Refactoring Test Code", refers to objects used exclusively for unit testing generically as "Test Doubles."  He identified several different kinds of doubles in common use:

- Test Stub

  - Returns the expected results, and/or calls expected methods.  Used to force production code down a desired path.
- Test spy

  - Observes the calling code, recording what was called for later verification.  Returns values that force production code down a desired path.
- Test mock

  - Initialized with a set of expectations that it will be called in a certain way, then observes the calls made and throws an exception in case of failure.  Returns values that force production code down a desired path.
- Fake object

  - Simplistic version of a true object.  Primary use is to stand in for a dependent component that is not yet built.  Often used to replace a database or service.
- Dummy object

  - Very simple object that meets a method signature requirement that isn't important to the test.  Null objects or null strings are common dummies.

In your case, these would be considered dummy objects.  They are only there to be returned by your logic, but their contents are immaterial to the test.

Comment: Thanks, very informative. The value of the objects does matter, as they're sometimes used in assembling the final expected output. Would you still consider these dummies?

Comment: @Deejay, if they return values I depend upon to make further decisions in the code path under test, I'd probably classify them as stubs.  If I only need them to come back with values to the test routine, I'd probably call them dummies. An example might be a Product object that contains a 10% Discount object.  The Product would drive the code into the discount logic, so it's a stub. If the amount of the discount being 10% or 20% doesn't matter in this test, it's a dummy. If I was making sure the 10% discount logic computed $1.00 savings on a $10.00 Product, then it's a fake.

Answer (score 1):

I call them "canned answers", but this is not limited to objects, they can be primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'mock object' or 'fake' is what you are asking for?

Comment: I was considering the mock object is the thing being mocked, not the things the mock returns. Always interesting to hear how other people name things though.

Comment: Mock objects mimic real objects' interfaces. And return prearranged responses.

Comment: Thanks - they do indeed. Do you know of any succinct and widely-accepted term for "prearranged responses"? That's the bit I'm trying to find out.